# Regarding NAD83 versus WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system

What might be the discrepancy for a survey line originally projected in NAD83 over 500 metres if the high precision GPS unit is using a WGS84 projection? Is there a possible also a cumulative error with distance?

Comment: That's way more than a 'datum' issue particularly between NAD83 and WGS84. I would look back at the original data. Was it DMS or degree minute and converted incorrectly?

Comment: There is little difference (within 1 meter of each other) between NAD83 and WGS84 but if you are doing a survey that needs a high degree of accuracy this would be an issue.  The error is more dependant on where on the globe you are working than over distance I believe.

Comment: You need to differentiate between NAD83 and WGS84 datums, and projections. Between datums, you can have a difference in the position, but a 500m line in one datum is a 500m line in the other, there is no difference in that range of distances. About projections, it depends of what projections are being used, and where.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a variety of issues. First I'm not sure if you mean the discrepancy is over 500 meters or the survey line is 500 meters?

What realization of the datums were used (i.e. is it NAD83 HARN, NAD83 2011, etc?) What units are used?  If they are both in feet, for example, what version of feet (international, US Survey?)

Also, WGS84 and NAD83 are datums and generally when someone says they used those as a projection they are referring to them as a Geographic Coordinate System rather than a Projected Coordinate System. For example a Projected Coordinate System would be something like "State Plane Coordinate System, Arizona Central Zone, NAD83-2011, International Feet." Make sure you're data are both in one or the other else you'll will need to do some conversions.